# mule invoke java component as array parameter

Tags: mule

properties file:

> `#torun='GSD11','GSD12' 
>   torun='GSD11'`

```
  <flow name="deleteInvoiceFlow" doc:name="deleteInvoiceFlow">
            <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${port}" path="deleteInvoice" doc:name="HTTP"/>
            <invoke object-ref="client" method="deleteInvoice" methodArguments="${torun}" methodArgumentTypes="java.lang.String" />
     </flow>

  <spring:bean id="client" name="client" class="com.util.DeleteTable"/>
```

Java: DeleteTable:

```
public String deleteInvoice(@Payload String deleteCompany) throws SQLException{
```

It works well for single parameter from the properties as shown above in properties file. But If i run application with below companies in properties

> `torun='GSD11','GSD12'

it gives error message as

```
1 (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException). Message payload is of type: String
```

How do I enable to receive parameteras array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mule docs says:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Invoke+Component+Reference

methodArguments="#[1], #[2]"

methodArgumentTypes="java.lang.Float, java.lang.Float"

but my list is random and it grows to 100s to 1000s, I don't want to put 1000s of argument types.
As a workaround solution I am loading the mule-app.propertes in java component and reading the property content.

```
public String deleteInvoice(){
      Properties prop = new Properties();
      InputStream input = DeleteTable.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mule-app.properties");
      prop.load(input);
      return prop.getProperty("torun");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the Mule message's Payload is a Object. Thus allowing it to handle any kind of object.

If you check the MuleMessage interface you'll see it.

In your code above your sending whatever comes from your inbound endpoint (http) to your spring bean, and you are assuming it's going to be a string.

Now the payload can certainly change in an http inbound endpoint depending on what type of request you receive (get/post/put/etc) so be careful with that.

Going back to your question, if you're positive the payload is going to be an array you can just change the firm of your method to that. If not I'll advise you change it to object and validate what's coming and cast accordingly.

HTH